# dont want to notify all members in play framework socket chat

Tags: sockets, scala, playframework, chat, akka

i am tottaly new in play framework web socket.
i downloaded a application of chat from the https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/samples/scala/websocket-chat

and i am learning it for the notifications in project. but the problem is that i am not understading the behaviour of the code. like in below code, i want to set the members whom twill recived the msg.
previusly `members` contatining all username of users that are in chat room, i modify it and set it to only one user "govind" but still all members are notifing,
simply i want to notify only some users

```
def notifyAll(kind: String, user: String, text: String) {
members=Set.empty[String]+"govind"
val msg = JsObject(
  Seq(
    "kind" -> JsString(kind),
    "user" -> JsString(user),
    "message" -> JsString(text),
    "members" -> JsArray(
      members.toList.map(JsString)
    )
  )  
)
chatChannel.push(msg)
}
```

and what it does

```
sender ! Connected(chatEnumerator)
self ! NotifyJoin(username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the play.api.libs.iteratee.Concurrent to find other options than broadcast (one to many). You probably want to read up on both iteratees and actors to see what fits your use case best.

James Roper wrote a nice blog article about iteratees that you can find here:
http://jazzy.id.au/default/2012/11/06/iteratees_for_imperative_programmers.html

The Akka docs are good for getting into how and what Actors are:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.1/intro/what-is-akka.html

Also, if you are new to Play then you should probably invest some time in getting a firm grip on the basic before jumping into more advanced stuff like iteratees.